Separable spaces that aren't countably tight.
Let $X$ be an hereditarily separable space.
I know that $X$ is countably tight, because: Let $A \subseteq X$. Then, $A$ is separable as a subspace of $X$. So, there exists $D \subseteq A$ dense in $A$ such that $D$ is countable. We have that $\overline{D}^X \subseteq \overline{A}^X$. Now, let $p \in \overline{A}^X$ and let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $p$ in $X$, we have that $\emptyset \neq U \cap A$ is open in $A$ and, as $D$ is dense in $A$, $\emptyset \neq U \cap A \cap D = U \cap D$. So, $p \in \overline{D}^X$, and $\overline{D}^X = \overline{A}^X$.
After proving this, I wanted to find examples of spaces that are separable, but aren't countably tight. However, I haven't been able to find any examples. Does anyone know any?
Note:
Currently, in $\pi$-Base, there are no examples of spaces that are Separable + $\neg$Countably tight.

Here are a few examples:
1.
Let $X$ be any topological space, which is not countably tight.
Define the following topology on $Y = X \cup \{\infty\}$
($\infty \notin X$): 
$\{U \cup \{\infty\}: U \text{ is open in } X \} \cup \{\emptyset\}$ 
Then $X$ is a subspace of $Y$. Hence, since countably tightness is hereditarily,  $Y$ is not countably tight.
$\{\infty\}$ is dense in $Y$, hence $Y$ is separable.
Of course, $Y$ has very poor separation, it is never $T_1$.
2.
$\beta \mathbb N$, the Stone-Cech compactification of the integers: Of course, it is separable, compact, $T_2$, but, less trivial, no point of $\beta \mathbb N \setminus \mathbb N$ is countably tight, see here, problem 54.

BTW, this example is contained in $\pi$-base,
they just don't seem to know that it's not countably tight.
3.
Both examples from above still have points, which are countably tight.
Here is an example without any point of countably tightness:

Let $S^1 \subset \mathbb R^2$ be the circle.
$X = (S^1)^{\omega_1}$ is a compact, topological group.
(Or, as user14111 commented, $X = 2^{\omega_1}$).
It is well-known, that $X$ is separable.
It is not difficult to see that no point of $X$ is countably tight.

Isn't ${0,1}^{\omega_1}$ separable but not countably tight?

@user14111: yes, sure. Would work as well.

Thanks, Ulli, great answer. Especially, the first example.
